# Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,\infty]}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n\exp(-ax)=\dfrac{1}{a-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Establish the following limits:

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,1]}\dfrac{n^2x^2}{\exp(nx)}=0$
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,1]}\dfrac{1+nx}{(1+x)^n}=0$
3. $\lim_{n\to
       \infty}\int_{[0,\infty]}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n\exp(-ax)=\dfrac{1}{a-1}$
   (In the last part, assume $a>1$.)

The first two were relatively simple to do. Just do tabular integration for each and then take the limit and you are done.

However the third one is giving me a hard time to show that the statement is true. I first integrated and found this large complex expansion. But this seems too complicated.

Can I get some suggestions?

Comment: Did you know that $\exp(c):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+c/n)^n$ and that further, this sequence is increasing?

Comment: Yes. So I should move the lim inside the integral?

Comment: If you know the MCT, you may switch limit and integration.

Comment: Yes, you can justify this using the squeeze theorem. MCT is a good way too

Comment: So I have done the switching for the first two problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\le e^x$$

for $x>0$ and $n\ge 0$.  Therefore, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^\infty \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\,e^{-ax}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \,e^{-(a-1)x}\,dx=\frac{1}{a-1}$$

for $a>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality),
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n}
&=\left(\frac{(n+x+1)n}{(n+x)(n+1)}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac xn\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac x{(n+x)(n+1)}\right)^{n+1}\frac{n+x}n\\[6pt]
&\ge\left(1-\frac x{n+x}\right)\frac{n+x}n\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
That is, $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is increasing in $n$.

Thus, by [Monotone Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem),
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\,e^{-ax}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\,e^{-ax}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^x\,e^{-ax}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{a-1}
\end{align}
$$